# Can't get rails rake task to play nice with crontab

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, cron

I currently have this shell script ...

nightly.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm 1.9.2
cd /home/appname/capistrano/current
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake nightly >> /home/appname/capistrano/shared/log/nightly.log 2>&1
```

I use it in my crontab entry here... `crontab -e`

```
42 20 * * * /home/appname/nightly.sh
```

When it runs I get this error

```
/home/appname/nightly.sh: line 4: bundle: command not found
```

**I am using RVM**

I've now Added some environmental variables to my crontab per @KL-7

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/home/appname
PATH=/home/appname/local/bin:/home/appname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/appname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/appname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/appname/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Now I'm getting this...

```
/home/appname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler
[minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /home/appname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
        from /home/appname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
        from /home/appname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you create this crontab entry manually or with whenever or smth like that?

Comment: @FrederickCheung **Yes!** thanks for asking, probably an important piece eh?

Comment: Does your rails app have a Rakefile?

Answer (score 3):

It could be because its throwing an error and you are not capturing it. Try the following:

```
01 04 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/appname/capistrano/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake nightly' >> /home/appname/capistrano/shared/log/nightly.log 2>&1
```

Comment: what will this do? sorry, try to not get in a habit of copy/pasting into the term w/o understanding.

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr of the process to its stdout. See, for example, [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) for more info.

Comment: The first redirect is for stdout ; the second one is for stderr. You were capturing stdout but not stderr.

Comment: If you can run it from the command line without errors, please make sure that you use the correct PATH variable in the command. Ideally create a shell script containing all the command and execute that shell script from cron instead.

Comment: Does it work from the command line ? If so, it should work from the script as well. However, you will need to export the variables so that the subshells are access it as well. Effectively "export PATH=blah:blah" for each of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `cron` can't locate your `bundle` executable. You need to find it (using, for example, `which bundle`) and then either specify full path to it in crontab or set `PATH` environment variable at the top of crontab like that:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/path/to/directory/with/bundle/
```

Comment: Ok, but nothing changed for `PATH` env variable. Try adding path to directory with `bundle` executable to it or at least specify full path to `bundle` in your script.

Comment: Updated again after following your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:
/bin/bash -l -c

Read:
http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/09/07/rvm-and-cron-in-production

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution:

```
* * * * * ssh localhost 'your command here...'
```

This will just ssh in to the same host (which sources the normal environment) and issues the command