# How to make crontab use the correct rake and refer to gems in vendor/bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rake, bundler

I would like my cron job, which calls a rake task, to use the gems installed in either [rails_app]/vendor/bundle or [rails_app]/vendor/cache. Currently, my system gems are out-of-date, but I cannot update them for various reasons beyond my control.

I tried using `bundle exec`, but this does not seem to work. The error I get is
    **usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in 'materialize': Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)**

I believe this is because my system's rake is out-of-date. I tried using  `bundle exec rake _0.9.2.2_ [my_task]` in the cron job, but the same error appeared

I tried the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem; this produced the exact error.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. How do I make cron use the correct rake version? And
2. How do I point it to gems already in vendor/bundle or vendor/cache?

Note that the site works when deployed in Phusion Passenger.

Comment: yes, i did that, without success. my command is `cd /home/[rails_app] && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake _0.9.2.2_ [my_task]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While hunting a solution for the same problem I found [this Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620137/cant-get-rails-rake-task-to-play-nice-with-crontab) with several tips.

the quick & easy way for me was to just run the cron command as login shell - like this:

`* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake _0.9.2.2_ [my_task]' 2>&1`

the ending `2>&1` is just to be sure to receive errors in cron log. also see `man bash` for further info!

Comment: I ended up using RVM and your bin/bash -l -c as a solution as a work-around. I will try your solution without RVM on another project, but I will mark this as accepted. Thanks.